# Failed validating 'required' in schema['properties']['rasa_nlu_data']['properties']['common_examples']['items']['properties']['entities']['items']:

Tags: python, error-handling, command-prompt, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I got this error on my command prompt while running a python file to train file using rasa nlu

i'm currently using windows 10 
rasa_core==0.8.2
rasa_nlu==0.11.4
python 3.6.7 
PS: i downgraded both rasa and python as the modules names in rasa's recent version changed and python 3.8 didn't support rasa respectively.

I'm relatively new to coding. I would love to get some help here.

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "nlu_model.py", line 12, in <module>

    train_nlu('./data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu')

  File "nlu_model.py", line 6, in train_nlu

    training_data = load_data(data)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\converters.py", line 365, in load_data

    return load_rasa_data(files)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\converters.py", line 267, in load_rasa_data

    validate_rasa_nlu_data(data)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\converters.py", line 253, in validate_rasa_nlu_data

    raise error

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\converters.py", line 248, in validate_rasa_nlu_data

    validate(data, rasa_nlu_data_schema())

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py", line 541, in validate

    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py", line 130, in validate

    raise error

jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'start' is a required property. Failed to validate training data, make sure your data is valid. For more information about the format visit https://rasahq.github.io/rasa_nlu/dataformat.html

Failed validating 'required' in schema['properties']['rasa_nlu_data']['properties']['common_examples']['items']['properties']['entities']['items']:
    {'properties': {'end': {'type': 'number'},
                    'entity': {'type': 'string'},
                    'start': {'type': 'number'},
                    'value': {'type': 'semphasized texttring'}},
     'required': ['start', 'end', 'entity'],**strong text**
     'type': 'object'}

On instance['rasa_nlu_data']['common_examples'][3]['entities'][1]:
    {'entities': [], 'intent': 'goodbye', 'text': 'Thank you for your help'}**
```

Comment: error shows that you have element `{'entities': [], 'intent': 'goodbye', 'text': 'Thank you for your help'}` without `start`  - so it seems you have wrong data. You have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using quite outdated version of Rasa, event before 1.0
The latest release is 1.7.0

You can find instructions for the upgrade [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/)

Could you try to upgrade Rasa and try again?